# C# Serializing JWT payload outputs incorrect data

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

After validating the JWT i need to get its payload as JSON and perform some post token validation processing on the JSON output itself by sending it as a messsage to another service the problem is the output of the `scope` field is incorrect. The serialization lib is Newtonsoft

It should be serialized as `"scope":["scope1","scope2"]` but instead its outputting `"scope":[[],[]]` and i checked the token itself, and it does contain string values and is of the correct data type
Code :

```
  services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
        {
            opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }
        ).AddJwtBearer(opt =>
        {

            var validationParams = TokenValidatorHandler.ValidationParameters();
            
            //opt.Authority = "http://localhost";
            opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            opt.TokenValidationParameters = validationParams;
            opt.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear(); // clear all existing token validators
            opt.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler()); // add JwtSecurityTokenHandler as the only token validator
            
            opt.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {

                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                     string token = ((JwtSecurityToken)context.SecurityToken).RawData;
                     TokenValidatorHandler.ParseToken(token);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });`
```

Parsing the token :

```
public static void ParseToken(string token)
{
    try
    {
     
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        
        var validatedToken = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(token);
        
        var payloadJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(validatedToken.Payload);

        // perform sending the token and other operations
  
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, for anyone using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
the problem was with the data type inside the "scope" array for whatever reason it was not being Parsed as string but some other data type, the solution is to convert it to a string array manually :

```
//read the token using the tokenHandler 
var clms = validatedToken.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "scope").ToList();
validatedToken.Payload["scope"] =  clms.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

this fixed the incorrect datatype and outputs the expected array